# Extended WPF Toolkit: "Blank" text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the RichTextBox from the Extended WPF Toolkit in my application. I'm saving the content (with formatting) of the textbox in a database and this causes some problems when the user clears the textbox.

When the user clears the text the formatting (XAML) is still saved in the database.

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox
x:Name="TbDesc"
Grid.Row="2"
Margin="3"
Text="{Binding Project.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
AcceptsReturn="True"
AcceptsTab="True"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<toolkit:RichTextBox.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
</Style>
</toolkit:RichTextBox.Resources>
<toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
<toolkit:XamlFormatter />
</toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
</toolkit:RichTextBox>
```

I would like to clear the cell in the database if there is no text, but the Text-attribute of the RichTextBox still contains the formatting-XAML and hence, this is stored in the database.